# Can you change the span of a control at run time which was created at run time in TGridPanel

Tags: delphi

I have an 8 by 1 TGridpanel control which normally I populate with 8 custom labels.  At run time I need to be able to adjust the number of cells in the panel and expand one cell by the number of deleted cells.  See example below...

```
Label0 | Label1 | Label2 | Label3 | Label4 | Label5 | Label6 | Label7

Label0 |          Label1          | Label2 | Label3 | Label4 | Label5
```

I can add and delete cells but I cannot find a way at run time to access the ColumnSpan property which seems only available at design time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan` properties are part of the `TControlItem` class found in `TGridPanel.ControlCollection`. You can find the `TControlItem` by `ControlCollection.ControlItems[Col,Row]`.